# what does export {default} from '@some-package' means

Tags: javascript, next.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

The current project I've started working on follows some weird way of exporting things which I've never came across before.

I've a File A and a file B, File A has a bunch of exports and

File A:

```
export * from "./lib/types";
export * as messages from "./locale/messages";
export { getInitialProps } from "./lib/get-initial-props";
```

File B:

```
export { default } from "fileA";
```

I don't see anything exported as default from file A, so what's the default value we're destructuring and exporting from file B. Also I don't see any import statements in File B, is the import implied ?  And is this a good approach of exporting and importing things?

Comment: "*I don't see anything exported as default from file A*" - yes. File B should not work, it should throw an exception when being loaded. Is anything using file B?

Comment: "*I don't see any import statements in File B, is the import implied?*" - yes, `export … from "…"` does declare a dependency on the identified module. It just doesn't import anything into the local scope, unlike an `import` declaration. "*Is this a good approach*" - yes, this is fine and normal. Assuming it works, of course, which it doesn't seem to.

Comment: File B is the next.js page router file.

Comment: Something that can trip up ESM newcomers is that `export * from "m";` re-exports all of `"m"` except for any `default` export.